# How to detect a reaction on an embed, and then perform an action depending on what the reaction was?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I have attempted to use several different types of a sort of reaction collector, and none of them seem to work, I will provide some code so that you can see what is the newest thing I have tried.

To sum up my idea, I have the bot send an embed with text to a channel when a certain command is run, it sends the embed and then reacts with two different options, I want it to then await the user to choose one of those reactions (basically react again with one of the reactions the bot used) and then perform an action depending on which reaction the user chose, I want it to then delete the embed and then perform an action.

```
message.channel.send(embedOne)
    .then(m => m.react(''))
    .then(r => r.message.react(''))
    .catch(m => {

        console.error('Emoji failed to react.');
    })
    const reactFilter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === ''
        .then(embedOne => embedOne.awaitReactions(reactFilter, { max: 1}))
        .then(collected => {

            message.channel.send(`You reacted wtih ${reaction.emoji.name}`)
            m.delete()
        })
        .catch(console.error)
    }
```

Comment: Define 'does not work'.

Comment: It quite simply does nothing, no errors, no console message, nothing. It acts as if the code wasn't there. Everything else works, just not the part where it detects the reaction and sends the message with what the reaction is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call awaitReactions on the message, so in your code it would be "m", so the code should look something like this.

```
message.channel.send(embedOne)
.then(m => {
    m.react('')
    .then(r => {
        const reactFilter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === ''
        m.awaitReactions(reactFilter, { max: 1})
        .then(collected => {
            message.channel.send(`You reacted wtih ${reaction.emoji.name}`)
            m.delete()
    })
    .catch(console.error)
    })
})
```